# An $n\times n\times n$ cube is divided into $n^3$ unit cubes. How many pairs of such unit cubes exist which have no more than two vertices in common?

Tags: combinatorics

A cube with edge length n is divided by planes parallel to its faces into $n^3$ unit cubes. How many pairs of such unit cubes exist which have no more than two vertices in common?

My solution:

Two cubes have more than two vertices in common if they meet with whole walls

1. Each inner cube of big cube has $6$ neighbours with which it is in contact with whole faces. There are $(n-2)^3$ such cubes.
2. Each cube on a face of big cube (but not on an edge) has $5$ neighbours which touch each other with whole faces. There are $6(n-2)^2$ such cubes.
3. Each cube on an edge of big cube (but not a vertex) has $4$ neighbours with whom it is in full face contact. There are $12(n-2)$ such cubes.
4. Each vertex of big cube has $3$ neighbours which are contacted by whole faces. There are $8$ vertices.

Therefore, we have: $\frac{1}{2} ((n-2)^3 + 6(n-2)^2 + 12(n-2) + 8) = 3n^2(n-1)$ pairs that have more than two vertices in common (we need to divide the sum by $2$ because without it we would count each pair twice).

There is therefore ${{n^3}\choose{2}} - 3n^2(n-1) = \frac{1}{2}n^2(n^4 + 7n + 6)$ pairs of unit cubes which have no more than two vertices in common.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom{n^3}{2} - 3n^2(n-1) = \frac{1}{2}n^2(n^4 \color{red}{-} 7n + 6) = \frac{1}{2}n^2(n-1)(n^3 + n^2 + n - 6),$$ but otherwise, your reasoning is correct.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{Cube type} & \text{Number of cubes} & \text{Number face-adjacent} & \text{Number non-face-adjacent} \\
\hline
\text{interior} & (n-2)^3 & 6 & n^3 - 6 - 1 \\
\text{interior face} & 6(n-2)^2 & 5 & n^3 - 5 - 1 \\
\text{edge} & 12(n-2) & 4 & n^3 - 4 - 1 \\
\text{corner} & 8 & 3 & n^3 - 3 - 1
\end{array}$$
Hence twice the total number of pairs is
$$(n-2)^3 (n^3 - 7) + 6(n-2)^2 (n^3 - 6) + 12(n-2)^2 (n^3 - 5) + 8(n^3 - 4) = n^2(n^4 - 7n + 6).$$